# Cad file for turnstile mechanism/ one-way clutch/ one-way rotation?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad, bearings, 3d-printing

I am writing my first 3D cad-file and I want to place into it a [turnstile mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile) (a mechanism that allows a fixed axis to rotate only one way, and not in the opposite). Are there cad-templates for devices I can find in some online-platform for engineers? I found [this cad-file](https://grabcad.com/library/turnstile-mechanism/details?folder_id=130515), though it looks too large and complicated, I want to place it in a device that is 20cm*20cm*20cm. As an engineer, where would you look for a template of a device you want to create physically? Or any suggestions how to create my own simple turnstile cad-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIhCPl8eb7s) - apparently what I need is a Sprag Clutch or a Roller Clutch. The authour of the video provides his 3d-cad files to a Roller Clutch [here](https://makersmuse.podia.com/roller-clutch), although they cost all together 4$. Anyways, I purchased them, because it would save me a lot of time and it looks like a decently working clutch.